# Как правильно инициализировать переменные объекта в Java?

Tags: java

Прошу уточнить какой вариант инициализации является наиболее хорошей практикой. Если ни один из них не является хорошей, то прошу привести свой пример. Конкретно интересует  пример инициализации полей объектов из других классов.    Спасибо

1-ый вариант:

```
public class A { String text; int count;} 
public class B { public static void main(String[]args)
     {
       A a= new A();
       a.text="Text";
       a.count=10;  
     }
}
```

2-ой вариант:

```
  public class A { 

                   String text; 
                     int count; 

          public A(String text; int count){
          this.text=text;
          this.count=count;
           } 

 }

    public class B { public static void main(String[]args)
         {
           A a= new A("Text",10);

         }
    }
```

3-ий вариант:

```
    public class A { String text; int count;

 public void setText (String text){this.text=text};
 public String getText(){return text};

 public void setCount (int count){this.count=count};
 public String getCount(){return count};

    } 
        public class B { public static void main(String[]args)
             {
               A a= new A();
               a.setText("Text");
               a.setCount(10);  
             }
        }
```

Comment: 2 и 3 с примечанием. Атрибуты класса должны быть `private` или `protected`

Comment: Да, спасибо, забыл.

Answer (score 3):

Для большинства случаев самым лучшим вариантом является вариант внедрения зависимостей через конструктор. Финализированные поля дают некоторую защиту при многопоточном исполнении, внедрение зависимостей через конструктор хорошо согласуется с принципом Dependency Inversion (Inversion Of Control) и считается хорошей практикой. Широко используется в популярном фреймворке Spring, не мешает Unit-тестированию и работе с заглушками (Mocking). Подобный код обладает более слабой связанностью по парадигме SOLID. Пример кода ниже:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private final SomeInterface someImplementation;
    private final OtherInterface otherImplementation;

    @Autowired // or without autowired if you don't use Spring
    public SomeClass(SomeInterface someImplementation, OtherInterface otherImplementation){
        this.someImplementation= someImplementation;
        this.otherImplementation= otherImplementation;
    }
    // class functionality here
}
```

Comment: Замечание по поводу зависимостей считаю уместным. Инициализировать переменные действительно предпочтительнее через конструктор. Хотя бы по двум причинам - 1.возможность объявить переменные как final, 2.конструктор именно для этого, собственно, и нужен, не считая самого создания объекта.А вот связанность тут не причем.Тут речь не идет об инициализации большого кол-ва переменных, тогда уместен билдер.Универсальный способ понизить связанность между классами  - создание интерфейсов всех классов предметной области. Тогда, один класс будет иметь ссылку лишь на интерфейс, но никак не на другой класс.

Comment: Готов аргументированно незлобно с пивом поспорить/подискутировать с кем угодно, что в 97% случаев это самый лучший вариант =)

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, посмотрите про happehs-before constraints и потокобезопасности конструкторов в Java информацию. Возможно вам не доводилось сталкиваться и вы будете кое чему удивлены =)

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович, во избежание неправильной трактовки моей мысли добавил интерфейсы

Comment: Ну вот вы переделали пример и доказали сомнения. А то все про final, это единственное с чем я согласен. happehs-before constraints  я уверен, что там будет написано, что безопасность будет в неизменности - immutable и я это тоже сразу написал. Про билдеры лучше бы не писали они необходимы именно для изменения предоставления при сохранении инкапсуляции, ну вот опять всё в кучу. Вот ответили бы до слово конструктор и вопросов не было, простой вопрос - простой понятный ответ. Знаете зря, я начал ведь таких ответ здесь, много и по-моему это нерациональная трата времени как и этот коммент

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei думаю, вы просто любите поспорить, как и многие программисты =) я не исключение)

Comment: А про билдеры я и не писал

Comment: И про happens-before - нет, не в неизменности. Наличие final - полей заставляет JRE принципиально по иному вызывать конструктор объекта и возвращать ссылки. По спецификации все поля объекта должны быть final для этого, на практике достаточно одного поля.

Comment: Кто что имеет против билдеров? Ведь все согласны, что вариант инициализации сеттерами - тоже годится. Ну а если полей, которые нужно сеттить 25 штук, то билдер - очень лаконичное решение!